# Merge multiple .csv files into one

Tags: r, csv, rbind, read.csv, do.call

I am aware this question has been asked multiple times, but despite of trying to apply the aforementioned solutions i was not able to solve my little problem:

I have saved all my .csv that i am aiming to merge into one folder:

```
> file_list <- list.files()
> file_list[]
[1] "SR-einfam.csv"           "SR-garage.csv"           "SR-hotel.csv"           
[4] "SR-IndustrieGewerbe.csv" "SR-mehrfam.csv"          "SR-OffG.csv"
```

the I use a `do.call` tio merge them all. Note that all the files have the same format.

```
sr.master <- do.call("rbind", lapply(file_list, read.csv,  sep = ";", header = TRUE)) 
names(sr.master)
str(sr.master)
```

however after inspecting my resulting file I have realized that only the first file has been imported. **What causes this problem?**

```
> str(sr.master)
'data.frame':   1941 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Berechnung: Factor w/ 51 levels "Berechnung 1",..: 51 1 12 23 34 45 47 48 49 50 ...
 $ Situation : Factor w/ 13 levels "Nach Massnahme 0",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ Sachrisiko: num  1857 1857 1857 1337 1342 ...
 $ PID       : int  2844 2844 2844 2844 2844 2844 2844 2844 2844 2844 ...
 $ Case      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Differenz : num  0 0 0 -28 -27.7 ...
 $ Prozess   : Factor w/ 1 level "Murgang": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Objektart : Factor w/ 1 level "Einfamilienhaus": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Without a working example, it is pretty difficult to diagnose. I suggest that you initially split the `do.call(.. lapply...)` into two separate steps. First, something like `myData <- lapply(...)`. Now take a look at the resulting list. check names of datasets. Make sure it contains what you think it should, perform `str` on each element of the list, etc.

Comment: Any warnings when you run only `lapply(file_list, read.csv,  sep = ";", header = TRUE)`?

Comment: @Jimbou, `sep = ","` for csv files not `;`

Comment: @Parth Chaudhary my data is separated by `";"`

Comment: @Danka, just a thought ... try `rbind` after reading files individually. Is it working ?

Comment: @Parth Chaudhary and everyone else - thank you for your help. I just realized that the problem is in the indivudual files. The merging actually works with my code as written in the question. - Should i delete this question? I mean it is wrong question and will not help anyone...

Comment: @Danka you should delete this. It may eventually be closed and then deleted, but you can save the community the trouble by doing it yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# Get file list
  file_list <- list.files()

# Read all csv files in the folder and create a list of dataframes
  ldf <- lapply(file_list , read.csv)

# Combine each dataframe in the list into a single dataframe
  df.final <- do.call("rbind", ldf)
```

Comment: This answer worked best for me as it loaded the first row as the top row. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Here is a simple way (and probably the fastest one) to read andbind multiple `.csv` files into one single data frame using `fread{data.table}`**

```
# Load library
  library(data.table)

# Get a List of all files in directory named with a key word, say all `.csv` files
  filenames <- list.files("C:/your/folder", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

 # read and row bind all data sets
   data <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread))
```

And in case you want to bind all data files into a list of data frames, it's as simple as

```
# Load data sets
  list.DFs <- lapply(filenames,fread)
```